# Missing/ unknown error in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this code in jfiddle it works perfectly fine, but when I put in my source code and try to run it with my localhost the validation is not working? Do i need a javascript link to make it work? Btw the validation is only allowed to input letters and whitespaces.

Here's the code

```
<input id="inputTextBox" type="text" />


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inputTextBox").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.charCode;
        if((inputValue > 47 && inputValue < 58) && (inputValue != 32)){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you included jquery.js on localhost?

Comment: Did you include jquery file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the jquery cdn link.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```